# Как добавить или сменить способ входа на Stack Overflow

Tags: поддержка, аутентификация

Для входа на этот сайт я использовал учетную запись Facebook, покуда там не сделали обязательным подтверждение личности.

Можно ли каким-то образом добавить способ входа в мой аккаунт?

Может быть вопрос не по теме сообщества, не знаю где узнать.

Comment: Если что-то не получится, пишите на Мету или через форму обратной связи.

Answer (score 10):

Способы входа редактируются в вашем профиле, вкладка «Править», пункт «Доступ» ([прямая ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/current)).

Чтобы добавить аутентификацию через учетную запись почты или соцсети, нажмите кнопку:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вы можете, например, добавить логин Stack Exchange. Он требует только электронную почту.

Чтобы «отвязать» учетную запись, используемую для авторизации, нажмите **удалить** напротив нее:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подробнее в справке: [Как добавлять и удалять данные о способах входа из моей учётной записи?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials)